# audioplayers doesn't run on Android

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with `audioplayers` in Flutter. The application runs on a Desktop but it doesn't run on Android and here is the error:

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers_android-1.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\player\WrappedPlayer.kt:271:21: warning: parameter 'percent' is never used
    fun onBuffering(percent: Int) {
                    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
FileSystemException: readSync failed, path = 'C:\Users\Aburas\Desktop\adhan\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk' (OS Error: The operation completed successfully.
, errno = 0)
```

[image: the result of that]

I tried to search on the internet, but I couldn't find a solution

Comment: The error message is telling what's wrong. You need to use a different API. What exactly is your problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Please make clear statement what the problem you have is.

What i found is the line you are showing in the code:
[audioplayers WrappedPlayer](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/782fc9dff24a2ab9681496fd7c4c8fed451eac35/packages/audioplayers_android/android/src/main/kotlin/xyz/luan/audioplayers/player/WrappedPlayer.kt#L271)

It has message `// TODO(luan) expose this as a stream` so it seems like there is work to be done.

If you precisely express your problem community will help

Comment: Yes, that's true. When I launch the application on Desktop it works. But when I launch it on an Android device or emulator, it doesn't work. Also, the error inside audioplayers WrappedPlayer as you said. This the first time for me to face an issue like this.

Comment: I launched another application using flame_audio and also I had the same problem. So I removed flame_audio. After that, the application worked without any audio package so I figure it out that the problem in using any audio package.

Comment: I had success using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) give it a try

Comment: I got you and I will try to use this package on Android but seriously the problem in using any type of audio package on Android platform.